# Sending Plotly charts in a dictionary via jquery (getjson) in a Flask app

Tags: python, jquery, json, flask, plotly

This works fine in my Flask app:

```
@app.route('/cb', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def cb():
    x = flask.request.args.get('data')
    fig = my_plotly_fig(x)
    return json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
```

with the following script in my html

```
<script>
    function my_change(val) {Plotly.newPlot('my-chart', val, {})}
    function cb(selection) {
        $.getJSON('/cb', {'data': selection}, function (result) {my_change(result)})
    }
</script>
```

But if I want to send multiple plots in a dict, it does not work. I tried:

```
@app.route('/cb', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def cb():
    x = flask.request.args.get('data')
    fig1, fig2 = my_plotly_fig1(x), my_plotly_fig2(x)
    fig1, fig2 = json.dumps(fig1, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder), json.dumps(fig2, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    return {'fig1': fig1, 'fig2': fig2}
```

with the script in my html

```
<script>
    function my_change(val) {Plotly.newPlot('my-chart', val, {})}
    function cb(selection) {
        $.getJSON('/cb', {'data': selection}, function (result) {my_change(result.fig1)})
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not a python developer, but I would assume you need to use `json.dumps()` around the entire response, not each individual property.

Comment: Thank you! I also tried this (without success). If I use just Strings in my above example, it works fine. Just with the Plotly charts it breaks.

Comment: Not an answer though. I suggest you to use [Plotly JS](https://plotly.com/javascript/) to create charts on the front-end rather than sending the chart data from backend.

Comment: Thank you @Ram! I think that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Response
@app.route('/cb', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def cb():
    x = flask.request.args.get('data')
    fig1, fig2 = my_plotly_fig1(x), my_plotly_fig2(x)
    fig1, fig2 = json.dumps(fig1, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder), json.dumps(fig2, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    return Response(mimetype="application/json", response=json.dumps({'fig1': fig1, 'fig2': fig2}), status=200)
```

```
<script>
    function my_change(val) {Plotly.newPlot('my-chart', val, {})}
    function cb(selection) {
        $.getJSON('/cb', {'data': selection}, function (result) {my_change(result.fig1)})
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Matteo! But unfortunately it does not seem to work. Do I need to change my script, too?

Comment: Can you print the result of this line `json.dumps({'fig1': fig1, 'fig2': fig2})`?

Comment: Yes. It starts like this: ```{"fig1": "{\"data\": [{\"domain\": {\"x\": [0.0, 1.0], \"y\": [0.0, 1.0]}, \"hovertemplate\": \"Status=%{label}<extra></extra>\", \"labels\": [\```

Comment: I have updated my response, now in your json you have two object, fig1 : {} and fig2: {}, so in your jquery request you have to access to them by result.fig1 or result.fig2

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's how I have tried it (as posted in my question). Unfortunately, it still does not seem to work :(

Comment: I suggest you try to make the http request with postman, look at the json response from your flask application, if it is ok, then the problem is in handling the response with jquery.